# Django: Ordering by the first value of a tuple

Tags: django, metadata

I have a 7-tuple of tuples as such:

```
POSSIBILITIES = ((1, "Something"),
                 (2, "Something else"), ...)
```

Now I have an `IntegerField` with `choices` in a model with the possibilities listed above.

```
class Something(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = "...?"

    something = models.IntegerField(choices=POSSIBILITIES)
```

I want the entries in the database to be ordered by the integer in each of the tuples by default. How do I specify that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ('something',)
```

The last comma is important, it is required.

Comment: For anyone reading this and wondering about the comma, that's how you write a 1-tuple in Python.

Comment: Python's use of a trailing comma to differentiate a 1-tuple from a parenthesized expression is a hack. One way to avoid being bit by this is to use a list instead of a tuple. (E.g "ordering = ['something']") I doubt there is any significant performance hit and Django doesn't care, it just wants an iterable. This 1-tuple snag can get particularly irritating if you have a complex fields expression for the Admin edit page.

Answer (score 1):

`ordering = ('something',)` should work. The integer values are what is actually stored for `something` in the database, so they would be ordered by the integers by default.