# blog.Post: (models.E014) 'ordering' must be a tuple or list (even if you want to order by only one field). in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, tuples, database-migration

I am making models for my django blog application. But upon running `python manage.py makemigrations blog`, I get this error message:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
blog.Post: (models.E014) 'ordering' must be a tuple or list (even if you want to order by only one field).
```

Here is my `models.py` file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft','Draft'),
        ('published','Published')
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='draft')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The error says that my ordering should be a list or tuple. But it already is.
I can't understand this error. Can someone please help me out? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: Ordering by the first value of a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697105/django-ordering-by-the-first-value-of-a-tuple)

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
ordering = ('-publish',)
```

Answer (score 2):

**You must change this:**

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ('-publish')
```

**into this:**

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ('-publish',)
```

**Note 1 the added comma after `-publish`**

**Note 2**: In python, (1) is just a number, but, (1,) is a `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it expected a tuple and that tuple has to contain a comma even when you are parsing just an item in it, the minus sign means you want to order from the latest ones.

```
class Meta:
  ordering = ('-name',)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Only one value without a comma at the end in parentheses "()"** is not recognized as **Tuple**.

So, this code is:

```py
ordering = ('-publish') # Is not Tuple
```

Same as this code:

```py
ordering = '-publish' # Is not Tuple
```

So, a comma is needed at the end to be recognized as **Tuple**:

```py
ordering = ('-publish',) # Is Tuple
```

In addition, **multiple values with and without a comma at the end in parentheses "()"** are both recognized as **Tuple**:

```py
ordering = ('-publish', '-created', '-updated') # Is Tuple

ordering = ('-publish', '-created', '-updated',) # Is Tuple
```

In addition again, **no value without a comma in parentheses "()"** is recognized as **Tuple**:

```py
ordering = () # Is Tuple
```

But **no value with a comma in parentheses "()"** gets error:

```py
ordering = (,) # Error
```